# Eclipse: Remove Eclipse generated .class and .project files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project with SVN version control system. My IDE is eclipse. Iniitally when I open the project, I edited something. Since this is team project. Someone else commit his own .class and .project file into svn. When I pointed out, he removed .class and .project in some particular sub projects. Anyway, I have .class and .project in all sub projects. Now I want to a clean environment, I want to delete all .class and .project files. Are there some script available in this forum?

Comment: `find . -name .project | xargs rm`

Comment: Do note that there is no harm in leaving those .project files around, and in fact it is Eclipse's idea to share them between developers. They do not contain local information, but key information needed by other developers to get up and running quickly.

Comment: What is windows? I don't see any trace of windows in the question. Maybe you should make that clear?

Comment: Anyway, I want to make a clean project. Thanks for the notes.

Comment: Sorry, that I did not mention I am using Windows 7, and Eclipse, SVN.

Comment: My memory is fading, but are you sure `del .project /s` doesn't work?

Comment: In your windows explorer, just do a search for .class and .project files and just simple delete.

Comment: Hi: del .project /s works fine. Thanks a lot! cheers!!

Comment: You should write it as an answer and accept it. That would make it easier for other users.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what OS are you using... If it's linux you can do it in commandline like that:

```
find /the/path/to/your/project -name ".class" -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a unix like environment then 'find' from a command line could do it. First cd to the project directory then
    find .  ( -name *.class -or -name .project ) -delete

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Maven as a build tool? What is your directory structure.

Any bin, out, target etc. directories should be on ignore list in SVN. You can use "add to ignore list" in Tortoise SVN or edit folder properties and set "svn:ignore" property. This you can do recursively. Mind that this will affect other developers too.

If you're not using Maven, deleting .project and .classpath might cause some trouble. There might be some project-specific settings set. Blindly deleting .project files is not a solution. If you use Maven, you can definetely delete .project, .classpath and .settings, add them to ignore list and re-import all proejects with m2e plugin.